# Storing passwords in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What is the recommended way of storing user/password data in the google app engine?

I am writing a Python script that needs to log into some websites using my user data.  (e.g. log into an investment account and then perform actions)

Comment: why not just use Oauth and have them authenticate through their gmail emails?... do you need SPECIFIC usernames/passwords you want to keep?

Comment: I don't think Oauth is suitable for me. For example, I am writing a Betfair bot for personal use. The betfair bot will automatically place bets for me using my personal account. There is a way to store a session key, but that will expire after 12 hours, or if I log into my betfair account from a machine that does not use the cookie.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. The other question is for user applications, where the user would not want the application to have their password. This application is for personal use, and will log into my own investment account with my credentials.